# Removing divs gives error

Tags: javascript

So I created a dice simulator with an option to reset the table. I create new divs with dice number by appendChild and want to remove it with remove().

Even though it appears to be working I keep getting errors.
The code and error is below:

```js
function addMoreDice() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numInput.value; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "diceStyle";
    div.id = "dice" + String(i);
    div.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

    document.getElementById('diceTable').appendChild(div);
    howManyDice++;
  }
  currentValue = numInput.value;

}

function removeDice() {
  var removeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("diceStyle");
  for (var i = 0; i < numInput.value; i++) {
    removeDiv[numInput.value - i - 1].remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="diceTable"></div>
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at removeDice

Updating with html, although there isnt really anything there:

```
    <p>Pick how many dice you want to roll:</p>
<input id="diceNumber" type="number" name="diceNumber" onchange="return addMoreDice()">


<div id="diceTable">

</div>
```

Edited removeDice function, sadly changes nothing, works, but gives errors

```
function removeDice(){
var removeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("diceStyle");
var value = numInput.value;
if(value >0){
    for(var i=value; i > 0; i--){
        removeDiv[i-1].remove();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're going out of bounds on `removeDiv`. You could add some validation to make sure that `numInput - i - 1` only results in values between 0 and the last index of your array.

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant html?

Comment: when you remove an item.... the stuff after it drops down an index. Loop backwards

Comment: Updated mkaatman, not much there though, almost everything is added with JS

Comment: epascarello, could you elaborate?

Comment: Start the loop from the end and work backwards....

Comment: Didnt change anything, works but gives error, edited main post with my loop, thats why I asked to elaborate

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be in the removeDice() function. Removing an item from the array decreases the number of items in the array (obviously), but the for-loop is assuming that the array still has the same number of items as when the for-loop started. So if the for-loop started with 5 items, and then removes one, there will be only 4 items in the array. Since the for-loop is assuming that there are 5 items, it will try to remove the 5th item in the array, but since the array only has 4 items, there is no 5th item to remove, causing an error. To fix the issue, loop backwards:
`for(var i = numInput.value; i > 0; i--)`

Comment: Changed it to that and it still doesnt work  function removeDice(){
 var removeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("diceStyle");
 var value = numInput.value;
 if(value >0){
  for(var i=value; i > 0; i--){
   removeDiv[value-1].remove();
   value--;
  }
 }
}

Comment: Perharps try:  `for(var i = removeDiv.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ document.getElementById('diceTable').removeChild(removeDiv[i]);}` I am not sure it will work; I have never used the getElementsByClassName method.

Comment: With your idea and some of my adjustments to the rest of the code I got it working, thanks!